# Populating empty folders recursively with Windows

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, scripting, batch-file

I have a huge series of folders, named 'A' through 'Z' such that each folder has subfolders in the same form.

For example, I could have a directory at this path: **.\A\D\E**

I want to populate each of these folders with an empty file (so I can commit it to a git repository if anyone's curious).

Windows doesn't have an equivalent of Linux's touch, but I have the GnuWin32 toolset installed so I can, in fact, use touch in my Windows environment.

I've started by creating a batch file with the following:

```
FOR /D /r do touch empty
```

But when I run it, the folders aren't populated. I don't get any errors either:

```
C:\sandbox>FOR /D /r do touch empty
C:\sandbox>
```

Does anybody see anything glaringly wrong about the line of batch script above? Is there anything else I can try short of using additional non-Windows commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the syntax of the `FOR` command right:

```
for /r %f in (.) do touch %f\empty
```

Comment: That looks right but it didn't work for me. I also tried adding the '/D' flag. No dice.

(for /r /D %f in (.) do touch %f\empty)

Comment: correction: it didn't work when I ran it from a batch file but it worked when entered into the command prompt itself. thanks!

Comment: If you want to use it in a batch file, you have to use `%%f` instead of `%f`.